# Unexpected scoping issue when assigning click listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

When my `loadNav()` function loops through the `nav` array and assigns a click listener to a dynamically-created element, all seems well. If I `break` on the first loop through the `navItem.id` is `'newGL'` and the second time through it is `'litGL'`, as it should be.

But when I check the listeners after the loop is done, they both have an id of *`'litGL'`* (and also a type of `'b'`). But the elements themselves have the correct `navItem.text`, so I guess I’m not understanding how variables are assigned within the passed function to the `.click` method.

Any hints why my first click listener is getting overwritten with the values meant for the second one?

```
var nav = [
    {
        id:'newGL',
        text:'new',
        type:'a'
    },
    {
        id:'litGL',
        text:'lit',
        type:'b'
    }
]

function loadNav(nav){
    for(item in nav){
        var navItem = nav[item];
        var element = $("<div>" + navItem.text + "</div>");
        element.click(function(){
            getContent(navItem.id,navItem.type);
            //in practice I'm getting two click listeners with a navItem.id of 'litGL' and a navItem.type of 'b'
        });
        $('#horzNav').append(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Q: Do you have a problem with my answer below? It pretty much covers every option you would need (and the cause of your problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is scoping, but you *really* need to delegate that event (otherwise if you had 100 elements, that'd be 100 events :/), then you can specify the properties you need within the markup using data attributes, something like:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".navItem", function () {
        getContent($(this).attr("id"), $(this).data("type"));
    });
});
```

Then your `loadNav` would be:

```
function loadNav(nav){
    for(item in nav){
        var navItem = nav[item];
        var element = $(document.createElement("div"));
        element.html(navItem.text);
        element.prop("id", navItem.id);
        element.data("type", navItem.type);
        $('#horzNav').append(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically it would be "100 of elements *all pointing at the same event handler*", so not quite the overhead you are implying, but yes, delegation *is* the way to go :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Is that the case? I always thought if you didn't delegate it meant that multiple events existed in the DOM. I've worked on a screen where there was around 200+ checkboxes and I worked on the performance of it, before event delegation the page itself wouldn't even load in IE (long running script error), I always thought it was the sheer volume of events.

Comment: The "event" are just pointers to the *same function*. The delay you saw was likely just the time it took to apply the events separately (which is a different matter)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Ah right, so it's the applying of the events that takes the time, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: e.g. if you have `$('.someclass').click(function(){})` and it matches 100 items, it is just pointing those 100 elements' click events at the same function. Behind the scenes that is the same as using an `each`.

Answer (score 3):

The immediate problem is that the navItem is not the same value when the event is triggered much later. To fix this common issue use a scoping IIFE (immediately invoked function expression):

```
function loadNav(nav){
    for(item in nav){
        var navItem = nav[item];
        var element = $("<div>" + navItem.text + "</div>");
        (function(navItem){
            element.click(function(){
                getContent(navItem.id,navItem.type);
                //in practice I'm getting two click listeners with a navItem.id of 'litGL' and a navItem.type of 'b'
            });
        })(navItem);
        $('#horzNav').append(element);
    }
}
```

Better solutions involve putting the require attributes into the injected elements, then extracting them at event time. This simplifies the event handler and removes the dependency on the original navItem variable.

e.g. something like:

```
function loadNav(nav){
    for(var i = 0; i < nav.length; i++){
        var navItem = nav[i];
        var element = $("div", {id: navItem.id}).html(navItem.text).data('type', navitem.type ).appendTo('#horzNav');
    }
}
```

and use a delegated event handler with a selector:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".navItem", function () {
        getContent($(this).attr("id"), $(this).data("type"));
    });
});
```

This works by listening for the event (e.g. click) to bubble up to a non-changing ancestor element (e.g. `document`), *then* applying the selector to the items in the bubble-chain, *then* applying the function only to those matching element *that caused the event*.

The upshot of this is the the items only need to match at event time and not when the event was registered. Great for dynamically added items.

`document` is the best default if no other ancestor else is closer/convenient. Do not use `body` for delegated events as it has a bug (styling can cause it to not get mouse events).